# What do the indices mean for the input/output in PyTorch's documentation?

Tags: python, pytorch

I was reading the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) for PyTorch's `Conv2d` layer when I encountered this:

[image]

What exactly do the indices behind the parameter names in the input/output section mean? `padding[0]`, `dilation[0]`, etc.

Is the reference only applicable when the layer is provided with a tuple? In other words, if a scalar value is provided, does it mean that all references are the same? Can anyone provide some clarification on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding` parameter accepts `int, tuple, or str`.

- If you use `int` as the input, such as `padding = 1`, then `padding[0] = padding[1] = 1`.
- If you use the tuple, such as `padding = (1, 2)`, then `padding[0] = 1, padding[1] = 2`.

I haven't tried with `str` though.

Comment: Thanks for the response, documentation wasn't explicit so I just wanted to confirm I was right.